# Not working onChange in wrapper for rc-field-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I made wrapper for `Field` from `rc-field-from` package like below:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Form from "rc-field-form";
import type { FieldProps } from "rc-field-form/lib/Field";

const { Field } = Form;

interface LabelFieldProps extends FieldProps {
  label?: React.ReactNode;
  onClick?: (event?: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void;
  onChange?: (event?: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>) => void;
}

export const FormField: React.FunctionComponent<LabelFieldProps> = ({
  name,
  label,
  children,
  ...restProps
}) => (
  <Field name={name} {...restProps}>
    {(control, meta, form) => {
      const childNode =
        typeof children === "function"
          ? children(control, meta, form)
          : React.cloneElement(children as React.ReactElement, {
              ...control
            });

      return (
        <div className="flex flex-col mb-5">
          <div className="flex flex-col">
            {label && <span className="text-md font-semibold mb-2">{label}</span>}
            {childNode}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }}
  </Field>
);
```

but when i want to use onClick in children of this `FormField` component like here:

```
<FormField name="test" label="Some Test">
    <Input onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)} /> //nothing print here
</FormField>
```

then my onChange or onCLick (nothing) is triggered. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my field wrapper and how to fix it to use onChange on my childs?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `onClick` and `onChange` to the children like

```
React.cloneElement(children as React.ReactElement, {
  ...control,
  onClick,
  onChange
});
```

after you also destructure them from props:

```
{
  name,
  label,
  children,
  onClick,
  onChange,
  ...restProps
}
```